# How to display multiple columns as separate bars using dc.js?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Suppose everyone was asked to list their favourite flavours of ice cream.
My data is in a CSV and looks something like:

> Name, Chocolate, Strawberry, Vanilla, Pistachio, Banana,
>
> Alf, Chocolate, , Vanilla, , , ,
>
> Bob, , Strawberry, Vanilla, , , ,
>
> Charlotte, Chocolate, , Vanilla, , Pistachio, Banana,

I want to display this in a dc.js bar chart with a column for each flavour and to be able to filter on the people who chose that flavour. But I can't work out how to do this.

My javascript is not brilliant but I don't think this is as simple as it seems. I have successfully produced a bar chart with only one flavour but can't seem to combine it with others. I thought there might be an innovative solution when defining crossfilter dimensions but haven't had any success so far. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not directly supported by crossfilter but there are hacks.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for the reply. I can see that question is similar conceptually but I'm having difficulty applying the logic (probably due to my unfamiliarity with dc and crossfilter). I also thought there might be easier ways around by using either stacked charts or composite charts. Do you think either would be feasible?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question! You want a tag dimension, aka [array-based dimension](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays). This is available in the community fork of crossfilter.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look